# C# DES Encryption example

Tags: c#, des

I've learned in school how DES works and I want to make an app that does this the way I learned it.

I managed to encrypt and decrypt (getting all kinds of weird symbols) but I never managed to decrypt my encrypted file. That's why I'm looking for a good example but can't seem to find one.

Do you know a good example project that does DES without using any built in libraries from the .NET framework? Or maybe you want to take a look at mine to see if you can spot what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Text I encrypt: Dit is een test om te kijken wat de uitkomst zal zijn!
Encrypted text:

```
AÐ±§.ŒœwNÜúÈúÛü¿áX¯fMå©
MËà>
¹ðLþa‚@šu
ñZ…U‚¬pÃ;¯        <- white spaces (added block)
```

Decrypted text: `붿뿯붿塐뿯붿礷䨟ꛝ뿯榽뿯붿湵뿯⺽뿯綽붿뿯붿␤雟ḝ뿯厽㼆붿붿뿯붿붿뿯붿뿯梽뿯Ⓗ⭑붿붿뿯붿뿯붿뿯碽붿⁅`
Used password: `steutels van acht tekens`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I could do that but we're talking over 1000 lines of code, are you shure? :)

Comment: You can use the [DESCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.descryptoserviceprovider.aspx) class available in C# to do the encryption and decryption. That page has an example of how to do it. Are you using this class?

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince `does DES without using any built in libraries` - The OP is trying to implement this himself.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, but this code does everything manually, from initial premutation to final premutation (all arrays are hardcoded, etc...) And it should encrypt any type of file eventually

Comment: @ispiro No I was referring to scott instead. Sorry ;)

Comment: I did not understand that you where doing DES from scratch, not using the built in DES, I would test your input and output code first using the built in provider to see if it works ruling that out as a bug, if your bug is in your DES implmentation... good luck. I deleted my old comments, you can delete your responses to me too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I know I shouldn't reinvent the wheel, but I'm not trying this to eventually implement this in a real-life application.
My input text file encrypts en decrypts fine with the built in providers.

Comment: @ispiro Nope, no examples. It's a theoretical book. And the 8 bytes are extracted from any password entered (just from beginning to index 7)

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91628/Simplified-version-of-the-DES-Data-Encryption-Stan)?

Comment: That should do the trick, thanks @Sam!

Comment: @Sam Why don't you post as answer so I can accept yours? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91628/Simplified-version-of-the-DES-Data-Encryption-Stan) on code project, that should have everything you need.

Here's the complete code from the article:

```
namespace SDES_Project
{
    class SDES
    {
        BitArray[,] S_Box1 = new BitArray[4, 4];
        BitArray[,] S_Box2 = new BitArray[4, 4];
        BitArray Master_key;

        public SDES(string _key)
        {
            Master_key = new BitArray(10);

            for (int i = 0; i < _key.Length; i++)
            {
                Master_key[i] = str2bin(_key[i]);
            }

            BitArray b0 = new BitArray(2);
            b0[0] = false;
            b0[1] = false;

            BitArray b1 = new BitArray(2);
            b1[0] = false;
            b1[1] = true;

            BitArray b2 = new BitArray(2);
            b2[0] = true;
            b2[1] = false;

            BitArray b3 = new BitArray(2);
            b3[0] = true;
            b3[1] = true;



            S_Box1[0, 0] = b1;
            S_Box1[0, 1] = b0;
            S_Box1[0, 2] = b3;
            S_Box1[0, 3] = b2;

            S_Box1[1, 0] = b3;
            S_Box1[1, 1] = b2;
            S_Box1[1, 2] = b1;
            S_Box1[1, 3] = b0;

            S_Box1[2, 0] = b0;
            S_Box1[2, 1] = b2;
            S_Box1[2, 2] = b1;
            S_Box1[2, 3] = b3;

            S_Box1[3, 0] = b3;
            S_Box1[3, 1] = b1;
            S_Box1[3, 2] = b3;
            S_Box1[3, 3] = b2;
            //---------------------
            S_Box2[0, 0] = b0;
            S_Box2[0, 1] = b1;
            S_Box2[0, 2] = b2;
            S_Box2[0, 3] = b3;

            S_Box2[1, 0] = b2;
            S_Box2[1, 1] = b0;
            S_Box2[1, 2] = b1;
            S_Box2[1, 3] = b3;

            S_Box2[2, 0] = b3;
            S_Box2[2, 1] = b0;
            S_Box2[2, 2] = b1;
            S_Box2[2, 3] = b0;

            S_Box2[3, 0] = b2;
            S_Box2[3, 1] = b1;
            S_Box2[3, 2] = b0;
            S_Box2[3, 3] = b3;
            //---------------------
        }

        public byte Encrypt(byte block)
        {
            BitArray bits_block = byte2bits(block);
            BitArray[] keys = Generate_Keys();
            return bits2byte(RIP(Fk(Switch(Fk(IP(bits_block), keys[0])), keys[1])));
            //ciphertext = IP-1( fK2 ( SW (fK1 (IP (plaintext)))))
        }

        public byte Decrypt(byte block)
        {
            BitArray bits_block = byte2bits(block);
            BitArray[] keys = Generate_Keys();

            return bits2byte(RIP(Fk(Switch(Fk(IP(bits_block), keys[1])), keys[0])));
            //IP-1 ( fK1( SW( fK2( IP(ciphertext)))))
        }

        BitArray byte2bits(byte block)
        {
            string bits = decimal2binstr(block);
            BitArray result = new BitArray(8);

            for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = str2bin(bits[i]);
            }

            return result;
        }

        byte bits2byte(BitArray block)
        {
            string result = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < block.Length; i++)
            {
                result += bin2str(block[i]);
            }

            return binstr2decimal(result);
        }

        BitArray[] Generate_Keys()
        {
            BitArray[] keys = new BitArray[2];
            BitArray[] temp = Split_Block(P10(Master_key));
            keys[0] = P8(Circular_left_shift(temp[0], 1), Circular_left_shift(temp[1], 1));
            keys[1] = P8(Circular_left_shift(temp[0], 3), Circular_left_shift(temp[1], 3)); //1 + 2 = 3
            return keys;
        }

        // decimal to binary string
        public string decimal2binstr(byte num)
        {
            string ret = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                if (num % 2 == 1)
                    ret = "1" + ret;
                else
                    ret = "0" + ret;
                num >>= 1;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        // binary to decimal string
        public byte binstr2decimal(string binstr)
        {
            byte ret = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < binstr.Length; i++)
            {
                ret <<= 1;
                if (binstr[i] == '1')
                    ret++;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        public string bin2str(bool input)
        {
            if (input)
                return "1";
            else
                return "0";
        }

        public bool str2bin(char bit)
        {
            if (bit == '0')
                return false;
            else if (bit == '1')
                return true;
            else
                throw new Exception("Key should be in binary format [0,1]");
        }

        //generates  permated array P10
        BitArray P10(BitArray key)
        {
            //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
            //2 4 1 6 3 9 0 8 7 5
            BitArray permutatedArray = new BitArray(10);

            permutatedArray[0] = key[2];
            permutatedArray[1] = key[4];
            permutatedArray[2] = key[1];
            permutatedArray[3] = key[6];
            permutatedArray[4] = key[3];
            permutatedArray[5] = key[9];
            permutatedArray[6] = key[0];
            permutatedArray[7] = key[8];
            permutatedArray[8] = key[7];
            permutatedArray[9] = key[5];

            return permutatedArray;
        }

        //generates permuted array P8
        BitArray P8(BitArray part1, BitArray part2)
        {
            //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
            //5 2 6 3 7 4 9 8
            //6 3 7 4 8 5 10 9
            BitArray permutatedArray = new BitArray(8);

            permutatedArray[0] = part2[0];//5
            permutatedArray[1] = part1[2];
            permutatedArray[2] = part2[1];//6
            permutatedArray[3] = part1[3];
            permutatedArray[4] = part2[2];//7
            permutatedArray[5] = part1[4];
            permutatedArray[6] = part2[4];//9
            permutatedArray[7] = part2[3];//8

            return permutatedArray;
        }

        BitArray P4(BitArray part1, BitArray part2)
        {
            //0 1 2 3
            //2 4 3 1
            //1 3 2 0
            BitArray permutatedArray = new BitArray(4);

            permutatedArray[0] = part1[1];
            permutatedArray[1] = part2[1];//3
            permutatedArray[2] = part2[0];//2
            permutatedArray[3] = part1[0];

            return permutatedArray;
        }

        BitArray EP(BitArray input)
        {
            //0 1 2 3
            //4 1 2 3 2 3 4 1
            //3 0 1 2 1 2 3 0
            BitArray permutatedArray = new BitArray(8);

            permutatedArray[0] = input[3];
            permutatedArray[1] = input[0];
            permutatedArray[2] = input[1];
            permutatedArray[3] = input[2];
            permutatedArray[4] = input[1];
            permutatedArray[5] = input[2];
            permutatedArray[6] = input[3];
            permutatedArray[7] = input[0];

            return permutatedArray;
        }

        //generates permuted text IP
        BitArray IP(BitArray plainText)
        {
            //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
            //1 5 2 0 3 7 4 6
            BitArray permutatedArray = new BitArray(8);

            permutatedArray[0] = plainText[1];
            permutatedArray[1] = plainText[5];
            permutatedArray[2] = plainText[2];
            permutatedArray[3] = plainText[0];
            permutatedArray[4] = plainText[3];
            permutatedArray[5] = plainText[7];
            permutatedArray[6] = plainText[4];
            permutatedArray[7] = plainText[6];

            return permutatedArray;
        }

        BitArray RIP(BitArray permutedText)
        {
            //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
            //3 0 2 4 6 1 7 5

            BitArray permutatedArray = new BitArray(8);

            permutatedArray[0] = permutedText[3];
            permutatedArray[1] = permutedText[0];
            permutatedArray[2] = permutedText[2];
            permutatedArray[3] = permutedText[4];
            permutatedArray[4] = permutedText[6];
            permutatedArray[5] = permutedText[1];
            permutatedArray[6] = permutedText[7];
            permutatedArray[7] = permutedText[5];

            return permutatedArray;
        }

        BitArray Circular_left_shift(BitArray a, int bitNumber)
        {
            BitArray shifted = new BitArray(a.Length);
            int index = 0;

            for (int i = bitNumber; index < a.Length; i++)
            {
                shifted[index++] = a[i % a.Length];
            }

            return shifted;
        }

        BitArray[] Split_Block(BitArray block)
        {
            BitArray[] splited = new BitArray[2];
            splited[0] = new BitArray(block.Length / 2);
            splited[1] = new BitArray(block.Length / 2);
            int index = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < block.Length / 2; i++)
            {
                splited[0][i] = block[i];
            }

            for (int i = block.Length / 2; i < block.Length; i++)
            {
                splited[1][index++] = block[i];
            }

            return splited;
        }

        BitArray S_Boxes(BitArray input, int no)
        {
            BitArray[,] current_S_Box;

            if (no == 1)
                current_S_Box = S_Box1;
            else
                current_S_Box = S_Box2;

            return current_S_Box[binstr2decimal(bin2str(input[0]) + bin2str(input[3])),
                binstr2decimal(bin2str(input[1]) + bin2str(input[2]))];
        }

        BitArray F(BitArray right, BitArray sk)
        {
            BitArray[] temp = Split_Block(Xor(EP(right), sk));

            return P4(S_Boxes(temp[0], 1), S_Boxes(temp[1], 2));
        }

        BitArray Fk(BitArray IP, BitArray key)
        {
            BitArray[] temp = Split_Block(IP);
            BitArray Left = Xor(temp[0], F(temp[1], key));
            BitArray joined = new BitArray(8);
            int index = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                joined[index++] = Left[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                joined[index++] = temp[1][i];
            }

            return joined;
        }

        BitArray Switch(BitArray input)
        {
            BitArray switched = new BitArray(8);
            int index = 0;

            for (int i = 4; index < input.Length; i++)
            {
                switched[index++] = input[i % input.Length];
            }

            return switched;
        }

        BitArray Xor(BitArray a, BitArray b)
        {
            return b.Xor(a);
        }
    }
}
```